# What C++ std compliant custom allocators are available?

Tags: c++, memory-management, user-interface, c++11, allocation

I would like to use some C++ std compliant memory management in form of a class derived from `std::allocator`, but able to allocate chunks of memory and releasing & freeing them in smaller parts. I only found boost::pool, but this is not std compliant in the above sense. Is there anything more useful around or do I have to code this myself?

(Note that the `std::allocator` is often useless for allocating many small objects, i.e. when using a `std::list`.)

**EDIT** to clarify.

Say, I want to use a `std::list` of many small objects, then implementations of `std::allocator` which allocate each object using `::new` cause significant overhead in run time (but also memory I think). It is much more efficient to allocate big chunks of objects and hand them out one by one. For this, I need a `std`-compliant allocator (doesn't need to be derived from `std::allocator`, but must implement the same concept) that can be used with any `std` library container and provides the required memory management, ideally allowing me to tell it how many objects I am likely to individually allocate.

Comment: What is the issue with Boost.Pool allocators? Why do you say they aren't standard compliant?

Comment: Please specify if you have any particular allocation/free requirements.

Comment: @Karthik and @interjay Let's assume I want to use `std::list` (as mentioned in the original question) but avoid the allocation of many single objects.

Comment: If you're looking to non-allocate copies, only pointers; use: std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<type>> ...

Comment: _"in form of a class derived from `std::allocator`"_ N.B. there is no reason allocators must (or should) derive from `std::allocator`, it's not an abstract base or an interface class. Allocators only have to meet the allocator requirements (17.6.3.5 [allocator.requirements]) not inherit from a particular base class.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "**the** `std::allocator` is often useless" ... do you mean your compiler's implementation? Or all implementations? They're not all the same.

Answer (score 1):

GCC provides a few [extension allocators](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#allocator.ext) as alternatives to `std::allocator`.

You haven't really said what your requirements are, so it's not possible to say if any of them would be suitable for you.

Edit following OP's edit:

> Say, I want to use a `std::list` of many small objects, then implementations of `std::allocator` which allocate each object using `::new` cause significant overhead in run time (but also memory I think).

Why also memory?  The overhead of additional pointers in each `std::list` node will be present whether the memory comes from `new` or a custom allocator. Do you just mean the bookkeeping done by the heap to track all the small allcoations?

> It is much more efficient to allocate big chunks of objects and hand them out one by one.

Have you measured it?

If you don't want the overhead of allocating lots of separate nodes are you sure `std::list` is the right container? What about `vector` or `deque`?

`boost::stable_vector` is still node-based but has less per-node memory overhead than `std::list`.

A `boost::flat_map<int, T>` isn't node-based and could be used instead of `std::list<T>`

Allocators are tricky and not always the best answer to (real or perceived) problems.

Comment: +1 for the hint of the gcc extension. What do you use? `std::allocator` for everything (are you after performance?)

Comment: Yes, usually just `std::allocator` for containers, custom `new`/`delete` for performance-sensitive allocation.